# Batch script to copy a file from one folder to another and add prefix to file names

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting

I want to copy all the files that contain a particular string to another folder and then add a prefix(a particular string) to the filename. If I ran the script again on the folder with the same file, it should replace with the existing file.

I used the code below:

```
Y:cd source
copy *place*.TXT Y:\destination
cd Y:\destination
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /a-d /b Traditional*')  DO (RENAME "%%F" "south.%%F")
```

Eg: In source

```
file1: traditional.place.monday.txt
file2: traditional.mountain.monday.txt
```

It should copy file1 to destination folder and then add the Prefix south to it

In destination folder:

```
file1: south.traditional.place.monday.txt
```

When I ran the script once it's adding the prefix correctly. If I ran twice, it's copying the file but it should replace the file if the file exists.

```
file1: south.traditional.place.monday.txt
file2: traditional.place.monday.txt
```

How can I do that, and please comment the script so that I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

It can't rename on the second pass because the file already exists.

Change your rename block to somthing like:

```
(DEL "south.%%F"
REANME "%%F "south.%%F")
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the file in source directory. if the same file exist then i can delete the previous file in the destination folder and the new file will be copied-can you please provide the script for that

Comment: what I suggest above isn't deleting the file from the source directory. It's deleting the previously existing renamed file, so you can rename the new one.